# Kernel loaded to memory but not working, may assembly format be the issue?

Tags: assembly, kernel, system, nasm

I'm developing a simple operating system for educational purposes. I wrote a simple kernel which role is to display a character in the screen by writing directly in the video memory (0xb8000). I'm using Qemu to test the whole thing. The kernel is as follows:

```
void main(){
       char* video_memory=(char*)0xb8000;
       *video_memory='X';
     }
```

I first generate an object file using:

```
gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
```

Then I generate binary file using:

```
ld -o -m elf_i386 kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel.o --oformat binary
```

When I enter the following command :

```
objdump -d kernel.o
```

I see this output :

```
00000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
   6:   c7 45 fc 00 80 0b 00    movl   $0xb8000,-0x4(%ebp)
   d:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
  10:   c6 00 58                movb   $0x58,(%eax)
  13:   c9                      leave  
  14:   c3                      ret
```

Which is a little not similar to NASM.

However when I enter the following command :

```
ndisasm -b 32 kernel.bin
```

I see this output :

```
00000000  55                push ebp
00000001  89E5              mov ebp,esp
00000003  83EC10            sub esp,byte +0x10
00000006  C745FC00800B00    mov dword [ebp-0x4],0xb8000
0000000D  8B45FC            mov eax,[ebp-0x4]
00000010  C60058            mov byte [eax],0x58
00000013  C9                leave
00000014  C3                ret
```

Which is exactly what i want my generated kernel assembly to look like.

The problem is that I think that the kernel loaded is the binary from the first kernel assembly.

I tried to write myself this piece of kernel in assembly using the code generated by the second command and it worked.

How to generate the binary for the second assembly rather than the first ?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT :

I forgot to mention that when using ndisasm command it shows that my generated assembly has a lot more unuseful assembly commands :

```
00000000  55                push ebp
00000001  89E5              mov ebp,esp
00000003  83EC10            sub esp,byte +0x10
00000006  C745FC00800B00    mov dword [ebp-0x4],0xb8000
0000000D  8B45FC            mov eax,[ebp-0x4]
00000010  C60058            mov byte [eax],0x58
00000013  C9                leave
00000014  C3                ret
00000015  0000              add [eax],al
00000017  001400            add [eax+eax],dl
0000001A  0000              add [eax],al
0000001C  0000              add [eax],al
0000001E  0000              add [eax],al
00000020  017A52            add [edx+0x52],edi
00000023  0001              add [ecx],al
00000025  7C08              jl 0x2f
00000027  011B              add [ebx],ebx 
00000029  0C04              or al,0x4
0000002B  0488              add al,0x88
0000002D  0100              add [eax],eax
0000002F  001C00            add [eax+eax],bl
00000032  0000              add [eax],al
00000034  1C00              sbb al,0x0
00000036  0000              add [eax],al
00000038  C8FFFFFF          enter 0xffff,0xff
0000003C  1500000000        adc eax,0x0
00000041  41                inc ecx
00000042  0E                push cs
00000043  088502420D05      or [ebp+0x50d4202],al
00000049  51                push ecx
0000004A  C50C04            lds ecx,[esp+eax]
0000004D  0400              add al,0x0
0000004F  00                db 0x00
```

Also when opening bin files using a hex editor i got different contents, the first lines should be the same but its not the case

Comment: You can use `objdump -Mintel -d` to get intel syntax disassembly. Note that "not working" is not a good problem description. Also, you forgot to describe how you are trying to load and run it. Finally, operating system programming is advanced topic, you should already be able to debug at least trivial problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I was missing some [bits ##] directives in my bootloader

Answer (score 0):

The "first assembly" and "second assembly" are actually showing the same thing.

They are just two different representations of the same machine code.

Look at the second column of numbers in both of them. Those numbers are the actual machine code that your computer will run. If those numbers are the same, then the code is the same. Everything else is just a fancy way of displaying it, to make it easier for humans to understand.

So no, the problem here is not the format of the disassembly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have any idea on the issue source ?

Comment: I imagine you're not compiling/linking/loading your C kernel correctly. Are you using GRUB ? Are you just loading those raw bytes at 0x7C00 ? Something else ?

Comment: I'm using Qemu to test, it loads the bootloader to 0x7c00 indeed, please look at the edit on the thread. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ogQRP.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2N3JS.png, these are the hex outputs .

Comment: Im loading the sectors after the boot to 0x1000

Comment: What bootloader ? It's important, because a bootloader might put you in protected mode and find your entry point. But otherwise the BIOS/UEFI will just start by jumping to 0x7C00 in real mode and if you put your compiled 32bit C code there it's not going to work.

Comment: Good point, i just figured out that the kernel i generated uses 16 bits instructions. Could you help me finding a set of commands that would generate 32 bits assembly instructions from c code ?

Comment: Right now you are generating 32bit instructions if you compile with `gcc -m32 ....`. If you want to generate 16bit code, I'd recommend using an assembler directly, such as NASM.

Comment: I currently want to generate 32 bits instructions but i think that the ld command generates 16 bits instructions from that , is it even possible? Because when i use ndisasm command to show the instructions it shows 16 bits instructions, while for the other it shows 32 bits instructions .

Comment: I think you need to read some more books and tutorials, or you'll keep coming up with more questions. Right now you're generating 32bit machine code.